# Excel - Is there a way to tell Excel that my sheet ends here

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I delete a ton of rows, how can I tell Excel to update its idea of where the data on the sheet ends so that `CTRL+END` doesn't jump to an empty row miles down the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delete rows or columns and want to make sure that the previous last row and last columns is truly forgotten and done with,

- delete the rows
- delete the columns
- save the file
- close the file (<-- this is **IMPORTANT**. If you skip this, it won't work)
- then re-open the file

Now the "used range" ends at the last row/column of the real data. Excel needs the "close operation" to re-calibrate the used range (for want of other words).